# A group of order $n^2$ with $n+1$ subgroups of order $n$ with trivial intersection is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The following problem is from my exercise sheet in group theory. I managed to do the first two items, but i am stuck with the third. Hints and comments on the solutions presented below will be the most apreciated.

**Problem:**

Let G be a group of order $n^2$ with $n+1$ subgroups of order $n$, such that the intersection of any two of them is $\{ e \}$. Show that:

a) If $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of order $n$, then $HK = G$.

b) If $H$ is a subgroup of order $n$, then $H$ is normal in G.

c) G is abelian.

**Solution:**

a) Since $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of order $n$ and $H \cap K = \{e\}$, we have that
$$
|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K} = \frac{n.n}{1}= n^2
$$
Then, since $HK \subset G$ and have the same number of elements, then $HK = G$.

b) Let $K \leq G$ such that $|K| = n, \ K \not= H$. By the previous item, we know that  $KH=G$. Since the left cosets form a partition of the set, we have that 
$$
G = \bigcup_{k \in K}kH.
$$
Now, suppose that for some fixed $k \in K, kH \not= Hk$. Since both sets have the same number of elements, then 
$$
Hk \setminus kH \not= \emptyset \  \therefore \  \exists \ k' \in K \setminus
\{k\},\  \exists \ h,h' \in H; \ hk = k'h'
$$ 
Then
$$
k' = hk(h')^{-1} \in (eH)(kH) = kH
$$
what is a contradiction. Therefore, $kH = Hk \ \forall \ k \in K$ and then follows that $H \vartriangleleft G$.

c) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a) you need to prove that $H \cap K = \{e\}$.

Comment: For b) you need to define $H$.

Comment: For b) you can't write $(eH)(kH)$ because multiplication of left-cosets is not well-defined if the subgroup is not normal; also, $k' \in kH$ and $k' \in K \setminus \{k\}$ is not in contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the coments, I will work in these questions. For the first two, it suffices that those $n+1$ subgroups of order $n$ are the only ones with such order?

Comment: Yes, but you still have to prove that.

Comment: Working on that. As soon as I manage to prove it I update the question. Thank you very much,

Comment: You are welcome to discuss the question [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) with me

Comment: Is it given that there exists exactly $n+1$ subgroups of order $n$? Or just that there exists some $n+1$ subgroups of order $n$ that intersect trivially? In the latter case you could not necessarily assume that the given $H$ is one of those $n+1$ subgroups?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you can actually assume so.

Comment: Why would we be able to do that @KennyLau? There could be much more subgroups of order $n$. For example, it is easy to exhibit five subgroups of order four of the group $C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ such that they intersect trivially. But, altogether there are 35 subgroups of order four. Not all of them intersect trivially, but the given five will. All of them are normal, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: No problem, @KennyLau. We are probably allowed to think that those were all the subgroups of order $n$. I just don't trust my parsing of the sentence 100% :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $G$ is abelian can be shown by the following counting argument. Apparently, $G = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}H_i$, where $H_i$ are the subgroups of order $n$. Let $x \in G$, say $x \in H_i$ for some $i$. Then, the centralizer of $x$, $C_G(x)$ contains at least $n(n-1)+1$ elements, since all the elements *outside* $H_i$ commute with $x$ (Why is this? Use the fact that, in general, if two normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ have trivial intersection, then $[H,K] \subseteq H \cap K=1$, whence all the elements of $H$ commute with those of $K$ and vice versa). Hence for the conjugacy class $$|G:C_G(x)|=|Cl_G(x)| \leq \frac{n^2}{n^2-n+1}.$$But one can easily show that $\frac{n^2}{n^2-n+1} \lt 2$ for all $n$. Hence $|Cl_G(x)|=1$ for all $x \in G$, which is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H,K$ be two *distinct* subgroup of order $n$. Now $\mid HK\mid=\frac{\mid H\mid \mid K\mid}{\mid H\cap K\mid}=\mid H\mid \mid K\mid=n^2=\mid G\mid \Rightarrow G=HK$

For normality of $H$, we have to show that , $gHg^{-1}=H,\forall g\in G$. At the contrary let there is some $g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}\ne H$. Since, $\mid gHg^{-1}\mid =n$ , from the first part we get that $gHg^{-1}H=G$.So there is some, $h_1,h_2\in H $ such that $g=gh_1g^{-1}h_2\Rightarrow g\in H\Rightarrow H=G$ , which is impossible. So $H\trianglelefteq G$

Now let $H_1,H_2,....,H_{n+1}$ be the list of all n-ordered subgroups of $G$. Then $\mid H_1\cup H_2\cup ....\cup H_{n+1}\mid =(n-1)(n+1)+1=n^2\Rightarrow G=H_1\cup H_2\cup ....\cup H_{n+1}$.Now let $g_1\in G$. So, there is some n-ordered subgroup $H_i$ such that $g_1\in H_i.$ Consider any $g_2\in H_j, H_i\ne H_j$. Now $g_1g_2g^{-1}_1g^{-1}_2\in H_i\cap H_j$, using the normality of $H_i,H_j\Rightarrow g_1g_2g^{-1}_1g^{-1}_2={e_G}\Rightarrow g_1g_2=g_2g_1$. So $\mid C(g_1)\mid \ge n^2-(n-1)$ . But as $n\ge 2$ $C(g_1)$ forces to be $G$. As $g_1$ was chosen arbitrarily, we can say $ G$ is commutative.

Comment: What if, in your last statement, $H_i=H_j$, that is, $g_1$ and $g_2$ belong to the *same* subgroup? Then your argument will not work.

Comment: Ha Supriyo, I see you changed your reply and added "my" argument.